# TypeORM in NestJS can not connect to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, express, nestjs, typeorm

I install the mongodb software on my own Ubuntu server and I get the mongo string just like this `mongodb://xxx:pass@42.212.159.109:27017`,when I type this string in my local terminal and use `mongosh mongodb://xxx:pass@42.212.159.109:27017`, it works fine and the connection is success. But when I use this mongodb string in my nestjs project, when I run `npm run start`, the terminal output `MongoServerError: Authentication failed.`

### app.module.ts

```
TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => {
        const username = configService.get('MONGO_USER');
        const password = configService.get('MONGO_PASS');
        const database = configService.get('MONGO_DATABASE');
        const host = configService.get('MONGO_HOST');
        const port = configService.get('MONGO_PORT');
        return {
          type: 'mongodb',
          host,
          port,
          username,
          password,
          database,
          entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
          synchronize: true,
        };
      },
```

The mongodb version is 4.1.3, TypeOrm version is 0.2.38.
Does anyone know what is the problem and how to solve it? Thank u.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have figure out what the problem is, as the authSource of my mongodb is not the same one with the database to save data. So I should set the authSource option to admin, then it works.

```
return {
      type: 'mongodb',
      host,
      port,
      username,
      password,
      database,
      authSource: 'admin',
      entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
      synchronize: true,
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try to use the Database URL connection string instead of host, port, username, password, ...

So instead of using this

```
return {
    type: 'mongodb',
    host,
    port,
    username,
    password,
    database,
    entities: ...
    ...
}
```

you should use this

```
return {
    type: "mongodb",
    url: configService.get("DATABASE_URL"),
    entities: ...
    ...
}
```